# Fibonacci sequence and divisibility.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci sequence is defined as 
\begin{align}
F_{0}=0, \ F_{1}=1
\end{align}
and for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 2$, 
\begin{align}
F_{n}=F_{n-2}+F_{n-1}
\end{align}
Show that for any positive integers $a,b$, if $a|b$, then $F_{a}|F_{b}$.

Comment: Do you know the general formula for Fibonacci numbers, that is, $F_n=\frac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt5}$? ($\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$,$\psi=\frac{1-\sqrt5}2$).

Comment: Something more generic: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/FibonacciGCD.shtml

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that it applies given my assumptions. I could be wrong. But the chapter I am dealing with is regarding divisibility.

Comment: First prove that $F_{m+n} = F_mF_{n+1} + F_{m-1}F_n$ and hence $F_{m+km} = F_mF_{km+1} + F_{m-1}F_{km}$. Then use induction.

Answer (score 0):

From your previous Q asked 2 hours before this one, for $n,a \in \Bbb N$ we have $F_{(n+1)a}= F_{na}F_{a+1}+F_{na-1}F_a$ so if $F_a$ divides $F_{na}$ then $F_a$ divides $F_{(n+1)a}.$

Comment: $F_{2n}=F_n G_n$ where $(G_n)_n$ is called the Lucas Series: $G_0=2,$ 
 $G_1=1,$  $G_{n+1}=G_n+G_{n-1}.$